# How do I limit the stack trace in DBIx::Error?

Tags: perl, exception, error-handling, dbi

The Perl [`DBIx::Error`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Error) module is fine for use in `HandleError` in Perl `DBI`.

I wonder if there is an option to pass some arguments to
[`DBIx::Error`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Error) down to  the underlying
[`Devel::StackTrace`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::StackTrace). That's because we use some really 
long strings as arguments in function-calls. If I now call the 
`DBIx::Error->stack_trace` method, our logs are exploding.

`Devel::Stacktrace` knows the parameter `no_args`  and `max_arg_length`
which are perfect for our needs. But how are they drilled down into 
the StackTrace  package?

The email of the actual maintainer of the module -  abraxxa@cpan.org - seems to be broken.

Is there anybody with a helpful hint?

Comment: The DBIx::Error author looks like it's: Michael Brown <mbrown@fensystems.co.uk>

Comment: The people in #dbic are also very very responsive.

Comment: It uses https://metacpan.org/pod/StackTrace::Auto under the hood as part of Throwable. That has some documentation on the args. Since all of those are roles, you'd end up being able to pass those args that you want as `stack_trace_args => [ no_args => 1 ]` or similar to `DBIx::Error->new`.

Comment: I've already contacted Michael Brown. He has handed over the maintenance of this module to Alexander Hartmaier. And Alexanders email seems to be broken.

Comment: `DBIx::Error` uses `MooseX::StrictConstructor`, so I cannot pass any other parameters, right?
Or in which way I have to pass the arguments?

Comment: Here is a example what I mean:

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I mean:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBIx::Error;
use TryCatch;

try {
    my $dbh = connectDatabase();
    doSomeThingWithDatabase($dbh, "i am a really long parameter and will not be shown complete in any logs");
} catch (DBIx::Error $e) {
    print "database error: " . $e->message . "\n"
        . "Trace: " . $e->stack_trace 
        . "\n";
}

sub connectDatabase {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $dbh->{ShowErrorStatement} = 1;

    # V1: works, but shows the full parameter
    #$dbh->{HandleError} = DBIx::Error->HandleError;

    # V2: works, but the stack_trace_args parameter gets ignored
    $dbh->{HandleError} = DBIx::Error->HandleError(stack_trace_args => [no_args => 1]);

    # V3: Any suggestions ????


    return $dbh;
}

sub doSomeThingWithDatabase {
    my ($dbh, $reallyLongParameter) = @_; 
    $dbh->do("selec foo from bar");
}
```